# Update CSS on Model Data Change

Tags: sapui5

Can we update CSS depending on the model data?

Here I am trying to toggle between `cursor: pointer;` and `cursor: default;`.

```
<core:Icon id="Submit Button"
  size="2rem"
  src="sap-icon://appointment"
  press="onAppointmentIconClick"
  enabled="{
    path: 'data>/isFree',
    formatter: '.buttonFormat'
  }">
</core:Icon>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding in Control with "class" Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42221962/binding-in-control-with-class-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

the answer of your question "Can we update CSS on Data bind" is yes you can with using customData with formatters and writeToDom property true and custom style like

`.sapUiIcon[data-yourkey="xxx"] { cursor: default !important; }`

Here you can find more details 
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/1ef9fefa2a574735957dcf52502ab8d0.html

But on the other hand this was a bug at the Icon control itself and fixed at the nightly(1.30) version 
https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/Icon.js#L443-L448

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind directly to the css classes but you can call myIcon.addStyleClass('bla') on the press handler and make it change accordingly.